# Displaying Related Data In A Special Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

In the world of ASP sure am new and find myself lost in the following example. Obviously need an expert to lead the way.

Got two models Teams & Tournaments with the following structure for the database:

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public string TournamentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TournamentDate { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamA")]
    public string TeamAID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamB")]
    public string TeamBID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamB { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public string TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Captain { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TeamA")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> TeamA { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TeamB")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> TeamB { get; set; }
}
```

Since a Tournament has two Teams therefore to have the relationships using InverseProperty and Foreign Keys.

However, because I seek to bring back a result in the sahpe of:

1. Details of the Teams;
2. Alongwith a list of Tournaments displaying the competitors in the following format:

---

TeamID

TeamName

CaptainName

TournamentID | TournamentDate | TournamentPlace | Competitor

...

...

...

---

therefore, using auxiliary models like the following:

```
public class TeamVM
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Captain { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<TournamentVM> Tournaments { get; set; }
}
public class TournamentVM
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Competitor { get; set; }
}
```

and to map the values from the Database's relevant tables using a controller like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TheAction(string id)
{
    Team team = await _context.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamID == id).Include(x => x.TeamA).Include(x => x.TeamB).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    TeamVM model = new TeamVM
    {
        ID = team.TeamID,
        Name = team.TeamName,
        Captain = team.Captain,
        Tournaments = team.TeamA.Where(x => x.TeamAID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
        {
            ID = x.TournamentID,
            Date = x.TournamentDate,
            Place = x.Place,
            Competitor = x.TeamB.TeamName
        }).Concat(team.TeamB.Where(x => x.TeamBID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
        {
            ID = x.TournamentID,
            Date = x.TournamentDate,
            Place = x.Place,
            Competitor = x.TeamA.TeamName
        })).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

But the result turns out to be complaining:

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

[image]

Thus the same highlighting the portion:

```
Tournaments = team.TeamA.Where(x => x.TeamAID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamB.TeamName
    }).Concat(team.TeamB.Where(x => x.TeamBID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamA.TeamName
    })).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
```

Trying quite a lot of time finally led me to find that while the said error occurs, if I modify the said portion to:

```
Tournaments = team.TeamA.Where(x => x.TeamAID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamA.TeamName //i.e. TeamA instead of TeamB
    }).Concat(team.TeamB.Where(x => x.TeamBID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamB.TeamName //i.e. TeamB instead of TeamA
    })).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
```

The result appears.

Thus, instead of presenting the Competitors names I can present only the Team's own name. In other words, TeamA's portion is unable to present TeamB.TeamName for the Competitor.

What could be the reason of, and solution for, the same?

Using the following code for the View:

```
@model TeamVM
<div>@Model.ID</div>
<div>@Model.Name</div>
<div>@Model.Captain</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Competitor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Tournaments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.Place</td>
                <td>@item.Competitor</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Looking forward for and shall appreciate your expert advices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having `public virtual ICollection<Tournament> TeamA { get; set; }` in your `Team` object sounds a bit confusing. Why would you name a list of tournaments as `TeamA`? Would you consider a more simple structure?

Comment: Try making `TeamA` and `TeamB` in `Tournament` class `virtual` properties so they are lazy loaded

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the topic @Stephen. However, declaring both the properties as Virtual, i.e. like `public virtual Team TeamA { get; set; }` and `public virtual Team TeamB { get; set; }` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Mithgroth! Using the terms TeamA & TeamB representing only the two teams in a Tournament, main purpose being to link the two tables. However, you may advise some other names if the same do play a resolving role for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo!

Finally, I did find a solution.

Wow! This world of ASP Core is amazing!

Thanks for the advice @Mithgroth however, can't deviate from the Database Model. But, if any further clean version can be advised I shall highly appreciate, provided the Database structure remains intact.

Anyways the solution I did work out after 24 Hours was an updated Controller Action like the following, remaining portions continuing to be the same:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TheAction(string id){
Team team = await _context.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamID == id).Include(x => x.TeamA).Include(x => x.TeamB).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

var gamesList = (from x in _context.Tournaments
                    .Where(x => x.TeamAID == id || x.TeamBID == id)
                    select new TournamentVM
                    {
                        ID = x.TournamentID,
                        Date = x.TournamentDate,
                        Place = x.Place,
                        Competitor = x.TeamAID == id ? x.TeamB.TeamName : x.TeamA.TeamName
                    });

TeamVM model = new TeamVM
{
    ID = team.TeamID,
    Name = team.TeamName,
    Captain = team.Captain,
    Tournaments = from x in gamesList
        .Select(x => new TournamentVM
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Date = x.Date,
            Place = x.Place,
            Competitor = x.Competitor
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Date) select x
};
return View("TheAxion", model);}
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another way of solving this, since your setup sounds a bit confusing for my taste.

You can simplify things:

```
//The same
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public string TournamentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TournamentDate { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamA")]
    public string TeamAID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamB")]
    public string TeamBID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamB { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public string TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Captain { get; set; }

    //Instead of these two
    //[InverseProperty("TeamA")]
    //public virtual ICollection<Tournament> TeamA { get; set; }

    //[InverseProperty("TeamB")]
    //public virtual ICollection<Tournament> TeamB { get; set; }

    //Let's just include the tournaments this team participated in
    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can just call `Tournaments` out using `Include()`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TheAction(string id)
{
    Team team = await _context.Teams.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TeamID == id).Include(t => t.Tournaments);

    //You should be able to eager load the teams at this point since you don't use virtual, put a break point to check. If not, you can load them using .ThenInclude()

    TeamVM model = new TeamVM
    {
        ID = team.TeamID,
        Name = team.TeamName,
        Captain = team.Captain,
        Tournaments = team.Tournaments.Select(tournament => new TournamentVM() 
        {
            ID = tournament.TournamentID,
            Date = tournament.TournamentDate,
            Place = tournament.Place,
            Competitor = (tournament.TeamA == team) ? tournament.TeamB.Name : tournament.TeamA.TeamName
            //pick the other team as competitor
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Haven't tested the code myself, so you are welcome to think this as a pseudo code. Let me know about the results.

Comment: Hi Mithgroth! Thanks for the interest in the topic. However, if one has to create more than one relationships, isn't it necessary to have equivalent number of Collections? [Link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) [Link2](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) TeamA and TeamB both pertain to the same collection of Teams, thus won't it be necessary to use equivalent number of either **InverseProperty**s or **HashSet**s? Tried to attempt your code but failed at the **migration** step.

Comment: Since the place is not enough to include this line in the last comment, am using this additional comment. Do note that a Team itself may exist either as TeamA or TeamB. As per the **TheAction** the main objective is to concatenate the Tournaments' list with the names flipped so as to have all the names in TeamA and TeamB be in a single column and the competitors' names in the second column and  thereafter filter the ones pertaining to the one, details of which are being represented on the same page.

Comment: You don't need to have a reference to `TeamA` and `TeamB` in the `Team` object. Are you trying to achieve `Team` + `Tournament` + `Team.Competitor` giving you a list of all other teams that particular team has faced?

Comment: In other words, you mean the two relationships can be set up without **InverseProperty**? Tried your code but at the initial migration step received the complaint by the Package Manager Console **Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Team.Tournaments' of type 'ICollection<Tournament>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

Comment: I'm just trying to confirm your needs, since I think that having two `Team` properties in your `Team` object is overengineering. Once you simplify that part, you shouldn't need any *InverseProperty*. Also my code assumes that the tables in the database are designed accordingly too. So either manually edit the tables to have such columns & relationships, or you'll be needing a new migration to tell EF to adapt your new models.

Comment: In short: Don't involve the database while doing your business logic, let it be a dumb data storage, because that's what it is for. Design your models as plainly as possible, and leave the rest to LINQ and controllers.